# How to obtain children of PrimeFaces DefaultMenuItem

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I trying build menu model in bean and bind it with tag p:menubar

```
<p:menubar class="menu" model="#{layoutView.menuModel}" />
```

All works fine expect one thing. The problem is that i would to obtain the following structure of menu (using menu model of course):

```
<p:menubar>
     <p:menuitem>
         <h:panelGrid onmouseover="$(this).find('img').attr('src','resources/images/template_2/header/home_hover.png')" onmouseout="$(this).find('img').attr('src','resources/images/template_2/header/home.png')" columns="2">
              <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/template_2/header/home.png" />
              <h:commandLink actionListener="#{routesService.redirect}"  value="Siema" />
         </h:panelGrid>
     </p:menuitem>
 </p:menubar>
```

like you can see. The p:menuitem have child h:panelGrid (this .xhtml page works). But i can`t obtain same efect through constructing menu model in bean

```
  DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem();
  HtmlPanelGrid panelGrid = new HtmlPanelGrid();
  HtmlGraphicImage icon = new HtmlGraphicImage();
  HtmlCommandLink link = new HtmlCommandLink();
  link.setValue(Helper2.transformStringFirstLetterUpper(menusItems.getAvalue()));
  link.setValueExpression("actionListener", Helper2.createValueExpression("#{routesService.contextRedirect('" + route.getPattern() + "')}", Object.class));
  panelGrid.getChildren().add(icon);
  panelGrid.getChildren().add(link);
  item.getChildren().add(panelGrid); // here i get nullpointer exception
```

I get nullpointer exception. I checked a source code of

```
 org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultMenuItem
```

and method getChildren return null

[image]

I wondering how I should do to put panelGrid into p:menuitem.

I tried also switch

```
 DefaultMenuItem into UIMenuItem
```

but i get the following error through creating a menu model

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 1
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.validateId(UIComponentBase.java:586)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.setId(UIComponentBase.java:412)
        at org.primefaces.model.menu.BaseMenuModel.generateUniqueIds(BaseMenuModel.java:56)
        at org.primefaces.model.menu.BaseMenuModel.generateUniqueIds(BaseMenuModel.java:44)
        at org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultMenuModel.generateUniqueIds(DefaultMenuModel.java:28)
        at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(BaseMenuRenderer.java:111)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
        at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
```

can anybody help with this issue I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: why not extend the  class and override the method? Or even 'override the full class' by adding one with changed code to your own project?